# Cocos2D, animated sprites blur

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've returned to using Cocos2d after an 18 month gap. My initial source for guidance has been the learn Cocos2d book by Steffen Itterheim and Andreas Low.

I have to say I've found the guide rather intuitive to follow but have hit a couple of issues.

The first is the animation of the sprites. I am without a doubt using the HD sprites correctly (this has been proved by renaming the HD sprite and getting warnings that the HD sprite atlas isn't available).

When the sprites animate, they blur. At first I thought this was a simulator issue, however, while testing on my iPhone 5 and my partners iPhone 4, the same blurring is experienced. The method I have used for updating the graphics is as follows: -

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
if (self.parent.visible)
{
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    if (self.parent.position.x > - 50)//screenSize.width * 0.5f)
    {
        self.parent.position = ccpAdd(self.parent.position, ccpMult(velocity, delta));
    }
            else
            {
                self.parent.visible = NO; // We've gone off screen so set to invisible. 
            }
}
}
```

This is invoked with the following method : -

```
-(id) initWithRate:(int)rate
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{
    velocity = CGPointMake(rate, 0); //-100
    [self scheduleUpdate];
}

return self;
}
```

This is used within a "StandardMoveComponent" class, which is added to the sprite node. I should add, the graphics all come from 2 sprite sheets. They're in separate batch notes, but added to the same frameCache.

If anyone out there has any suggestions what I can do to prevent the blurring, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: what are the frame names in the -hd atlas? They need to be *without* the -hd suffix

Comment: Hi - the frame names are the same, so for example, in the file obstacles.pvr, they start with "obstacle1.png" and in the obstacles-hd.pvr file, they also start with "obstacle1.png".

Comment: The graphics are perfect when they aren't moving. When they move, It's hard to make out detail. This was not the experience I had 18 months ago...